# How to send email notifications to registered users on a PHP/MySQL website

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a website as my final year project at College and I am stuck on how i can send notifications to specific users on my site. For example when a lecturer uploads a file i.e an assignment on the site, only the students taking that course should receive a notification via email saying they have an assignment.

I already have their emails in the database. I would also like to know how I can make a logged in user see information that is only relevant to them and not make them search for what they need. I use DreamWeaver for the site and using WAMP as my testing server.

Comment: "only the students taking that course" - I suspect we will need to see your database structure (in your question please). Do you have a table relationship between student and course? If so, when an upload happens, determine what course the material is for, do a query to list the students on that course, and send each of them an email using a mailer library.

Comment: It is preferable to do your mailing offline (e.g. on a cron) but you can do it in a web request if you have small numbers of emails to send (sometimes the queries and email actions can take a long time, and cause a web request to time out).

Comment: Mr. Halfer thank you for your comment, I have not created any relationships in my database, the tables are just independent so to speak but thank you for giving me that idea, it looks like I may have to restructure my database and if its not too much to ask may I please have your email address? Am very new to php and I know I can teach myself but I could really use someone with your knowledge to assist when am stuck, or alternatively just post links of tutorials that u know will help me. Will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You don't have to create relationships (constraints) for the database to work, but without more information it will be hard to help you. See my profile if you want a substantial PHP/database tutorial to work through. I tend to discourage new posters here from asking for contact details, since it may create an expectation that volunteers are happy to take on free private tuition. You might be best off joining a new programmers community, such as Code Newbies.

Comment: Understood. I however aren't new to programming, it's just php. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very general question.

To send mail check out the mail function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

To log users in and keep track of them, use session management: 
http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Thank you sir, am still new to php and MySQL that's why it may seem general. I have looked up those thinks and proving to be very helpful. Thank you very much